# Firebase authentication exception too-many-requests

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase authentication with my flutter app, and when the user tries to log in with the wrong password 6 times get blocked with the `too-many-request` error. Is there any way we can change this to at least 10 or Is there something that I can change on my side?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you've added SHA certificate fingerprints in your firebase project